# Why is an object array created inside the object array class?

Tags: java, android, arrays

[image: head first android development page]

So I am reading the head first android development book, and alittle confused on one of the pages.

From the code, it is showing the object array being created inside the object array class itself using (new drink()). This is abit confusing for me because I thought normally the array would be created inside a main rather than in the object itself.
Can anyone help explain why?

Thank you.!

Comment: It is being initialized in a static block.  Not the way I would do it, but it is valid

Comment: well I suppose that It is because the constructor is private (so you cannot create other drinks from outside), the good thing is that it is static and you have a limited list of drinks, but for me is also strange to see this construction.

Comment: If I would have a static and limited list of drinks (as constructor is private) I would go rather to an Enumeration

Comment: @vmrvictor Maybe the client code needs to access drinks by index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is abit confusing for me because I thought normally the array would be created inside a main rather than in the object itself.

No. In Android development, you almost never write code in the `main` method.

A `Drink[]` can be created in many places. In your example, there is a static field called `drinks` in the class `Drink`. An array of drinks is created to assign to that field.

The `drinks` field's purpose is likely to allow easy access of the different types of drinks such as Latte and Cappuccino. You don't have to create the drinks objects in the client code. You can just use `Drink.drinks[0]` or `Drink.drinks[1]`. In addition, the `Drink` constructor is private, so the `drinks` array is also your only way of accessing `Drink` objects from the outside.

It might seem counter-intuitive or even paradoxical at first to have an instance of a class in that class. But note how classes are reference types. `Drink` is just storing *references* to other `Drink` objects. Not to mention that `drinks` is static, so it belongs to the class itself, instead of `Drink` instances.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, really appreciate it. I am still slowly learning android development.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been stated in the comments, the `constructor` of the `Drink` class, is set as private, thus there is no way that you can initialize `Drink` objects outside that class.

Having the creation of the `drinks` array allows you a quick an easy (albeit, not *traditional*, if you will) access to instances of said objects.

Seeing that this is a tutorial, my guess is that eventually, the constructor will be marked as `public`, and the author will introduce the concept of a service or some other mechanism which your Android app will use to get `Drink` objects.

The service layer could theoretically be getting these objects from a file, service (REST, SOAP, etc.),  Database, or some other data source.

Comment: _eventually, the constructor will be marked as public_ - or later in the tutorial they will use the `Builder` pattern to build an external `Drinks` array.